# Android project broken after Blue Screen on Windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio

I re-opened my Android Project after blue screen on my machine running Windows 10, all classes and components are unfound. Anybody any idea? I tried re-build and re-start my machines n times.

Comment: Did you check in the StudioProjects directory if the classes exist there or not ?

Comment: Try to clean and then build your project again, also do this File>Invalid cache / Restart, give it a try

Comment: Invalidate cache and clean. Check project build files for any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to CmosBattery's comment:

File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart ... -> Invalidate and Restart.

This lets Android Studio basically forget everything it knows about your project and forces it to reinitalize everything.
I suspect, that the bluescreen prevented Android Studio from writing a file and so the project state got corrupt.

If this still fails, I recommend to check out a fresh copy and if you do not use source control yet (do it now :)) backup your files, create a new project and copy them back into the newly created project.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your module(-s) uses valid Android SDK: press Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S and check modules one by one. May be the same validation should be done in build.gradle script

Answer (score 0):

Just check your project at its path in Windows File Explorer. If the project exists -with all its files (java, layouts, manifests, gradles and other project files)- just go to Android Studio--> File --> Open --> Your project root directory.
It will rebuild the project as new
Hope it helps